# Visual Basic: How I Can put my work at backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm trying to do screenshot every x second and run it on backgroundworker
but I can't stop it.
Here is my class Form:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
Dim rdm As New Random()
Dim ButtonOneClick As Boolean 'Make sure this is before all subs
Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork

End Sub
'run and save screen-shoot'
Sub GetData()
 'My code to save screen shot'
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
    If bw.CancellationPending Then
        bw.CancelAsync()
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'cancel
    If bw.IsBusy AndAlso bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
        bw.CancelAsync()
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim myThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetData)
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    For x As Integer = 1 To 15
        If bw.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        ' Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
        myThread.Start()
        bw.ReportProgress(3000)

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub bw_Down()
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub

End Class
```

I had been looking for solution, but it didn't work. 
I'm new to Visual basic. So; hope you ignore my mistakes
Any help please

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum needed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You are calling Start multiple times on the same thread, I think that is a mistake. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @fofik thank you for your replay, exact becouse if not my form stuck  and i can't press any button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose using either a Thread or a BackgroundWorker, not both.
Cause BackgroundWorker is a Thread itself, so it won't make your form freeze.
Change bw_DoWork to:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    For x As Integer = 1 To 15
        If sender.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
        GetData()  'Screenshot
        Thread.Sleep(1000)  'The delay between screenshots (ex: 1000 means 1sec)
        bw.ReportProgress(x)  'Report Progress (1 to 15)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: but i still can't stop it

Comment: I think clicking on Button2 can stop it.

Comment: Thank you @J3soon has been helpful, but I had to remove GetData() from Sub GetData